# ¿Como puedo leer solo un mensaje del serial port en python?

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi

Buenas gente, resulta que estoy comunicando un Arduino UNO con una RaspberryPI y lo que me ocurre es que cuando se presiona un boton Arduino le envia por serial un simple numero a RaspberryPi y esta cuando lo recive emitira un sonido, la cuestion es que para evitar gente molesta presionando el boton muchas veces y trancando el sistema, le he puesto un delay, pero al parecer esto no sirve, ya que si presionas muchas veces el boton, es como si el serial quedase en espera y si presionas 5 veces el boton, cada 10 segundos se emitira el sonido ya que siguen llegando mensajes del serial, hasta las 5 veces que has presionado el boton, es como si eso quedara en una cola de espera al usar el sleep(). La pregunta es, como puedo modificar mi codigo para que reciba 1 mensaje del serial, cada 10s y las demas pulsaciones las descarte si estan dentro de esos 10s.

Code:

```js
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',9600)
s = [0]
try:
    while True:
        read_serial=ser.readline()
        print read_serial
        playSong()
        sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Efectivamente, los has notado, por más que hagas un `sleep` los mensajes siguen llegando, por lo que la alternativa en realidad, es ignorarlos hasta que haya pasado el tiempo que quieres. Una forma de hacerlo es la siguiente:

```
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',9600)
s = [0]
last_time = 0
try:
    while True:
        read_serial=ser.readline()
        print read_serial
        if time.time() - last_time >= 10:
          playSong()
          last_time = time.time()
```

Usamos la función [`time.time()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.time) que devuelve el número de segundos desde el 1/1/1970 a las 00:00:00 y lo verificamos versus una variable `last_time` que tiene el mismo dato pero de la última ejecución de `playSong()` (o `0` si es la primer ejecución). Esto debiera imprimirte por consola todos los datos recibidos, pero solo al cumplir los 10 segundos se ejecutará `playSong()`.

Answer (score 1):

Ocurre exactamente lo que comentas, si se siguen enviando datos durante el delay, estos quedan en el buffer a la espera de ser leídos. En tu caso debería bastar con limpiar todos los datos presentes en el buffer y posteriormente leer a la espera de que lleguen nuevos. Esto se hace con [`flushInput`](http://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.reset_input_buffer):

```
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',9600)
s = [0]
try:
    while True:
        ser.flushInput()
        read_serial=ser.readline()
        print read_serial
        playSong()
        sleep(10)
```

> **Nota**: si la información llega como bloques de bytes cabe la posibilidad de que se corte la cadena a causa del flush si este coincide con el momento en el que se está escribiendo, perdiendo datos en el proceso. Si este es el caso debes implementar algún método para evitar esto. Una posibilidad es hacer que Arduino envie los datos junto a un delimitador al inicio de la cadena, de forma que al leer se pueda comprobar si está integra o fue parcialmente eliminada por el flush.

Answer (score -1):

Cuando pases los 10 segundos en tu RaspberryPI, has que este, envie una señal a arduino para indicar que ya puede enviar datos, y así haces recibir datos cuando te conviene.

Comment: que tal Brucce, seria bueno que ayudes mostrando codigo sobre como deberia ser... Por favor, date una vuelta por [answer] para mas informacion